# Why can't JavaFX be packaged with the .jar file?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, packaging

I had the following error where the json.org dependency was not being included in the final .jar file.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONTokener
        at gui.Main.lambda$awake$0(Main.java:91)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONTokener
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 2 more
```

I then learnt that you can add the json.org jar file as an "Extracted Directory" which solved my problem. After doing this I thought I would try to do the same for JavaFX. Upon trying to add it as an "Extracted Directory" I noticed it was already listed there (as shown in the image below).

[image]

However, if I try to run the jar file using `java -jar [filename].jar`, I get `Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application`. I can run it using `java -jar --module-path /usr/local/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml [filename].jar` but this shouldn't be necessary in theory. I was wondering if anyone knows why this does not work? Thanks.

Note: Packaging JavaFX would be really useful as it means I can just send the .jar file and it will work out of the box without the user needing to setup extra dependencies.

Comment: Have you considered [java packager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/packager.html)?

Comment: When the JavaFX libraries are on the classpath (as they would be when packaged in a fat JAR) instead of the modulepath, the main class **must not** be a subtype of `Application`. Create a separate "launcher" class whose main method simply calls `Application.launch(YourAppClass.class, args)`.

Comment: "_Note: Packaging JavaFX would be really useful as it means I can just send the .jar file and it will work out of the box without the user needing to setup extra dependencies_" – keep in mind that JavaFX contains platform-specific native code; a fat JAR containing the Windows version of JavaFX won't run on Linux, for example. You can get around this, I believe, by packaging every platform-version of JavaFX into a single JAR file.

Comment: Also, in addition to the suggestion from @Abra (I believe `javapackager` was removed in Java 11), you may want to consider using [`jpackage`](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/343). The tool is available with [early-access versions of Java 14](https://jdk.java.net/jpackage/).

Answer (score 1):

I remember I have the same issue when packing the JavaFX project.
And the solution is building the fat jar (including all dependencies)
If you use the maven, you can search 2 keyword: `maven-assembly-plugin` and `maven-dependency-plugin`

`maven-assembly-plugin` will help you build the fat jar file

`maven-dependency-plugin` will help you copy external jar file (not manage by maven repository)

```
 <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>package.mainclass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```